# Mobilefirst - Get push notification payload when application is closed

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

When i receive a push notification when the application is closed and i click on it, only the application open and nothing happen,

it only show me popup when application is open or reduced

What to do ?

thanks

Comment: Open the application how - from the notification itself or from the app icon? What is your mobilefirst version AND full build number?

Comment: Open the application from the notification in notification bar (the application is fully closed)

"WORKLIGHT_PLATFORM_VERSION": "6.3.0.0",

Comment: What is your mobilefirst version and build number? where are you testing this? android?windows phone? ios?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers, i am testing the app on ANDROID, my build number is : 6.3.0.00-20151004-0029

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a defect in the product - you need to open an IBM PMR (support ticket) in order for the development team to investigate and possibly provide a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Worklight 6.2, using Unicast Push Notifications.
I think the problem is that the Push Notification Listener gets initialized after the payload is actually processed.

The workaround I found is to force a (even fake) notification subscription after the application connects to the Worklight Server (which means on the success of WL.Client.connect or on the response of the first adapter call).

```
 WL.Client.Push.subscribe("myPush", {
        onSuccess : doSubscribeSuccess,
        onFailure : doSubscribeFailure
 });
```

Note that this will not work if you are using EventSource based notifications, but only Broadcast, Unicast and Tag. I think you can make it work also with EventSource, but it would be a bit more complicated as you will have to also handle the registration to the event.